# storing array values into csv colums

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a hash that needs to be written to a csv which is done via the code below.

```
require 'csv'

my_array = [ {name: 'Toyota', model: 'Corolla', engine: [ 4, 6]},{name: 'Honda', model: 'Civic', engine: [ 6, 8]} ]


CSV.open("my_csv.csv", "w", headers: my_array.first.keys, :write_headers => true) do |csv|
  my_array.each do |hash|
    csv << hash.values
  end
end
```

As you would see there is an array of values stored in one of the keys - `engine`. In my csv it looks like below.

```
name,model,engine
Toyota,Corolla,"[4, 6]"
Honda,Civic,"[6, 8]"
```

Instead of having the `engine` column in the above format like `"[4, 6]"`, how can I get it like `4,6` while keeping the csv formatting. What is the typical convention when one have to store an array of values in a csv column ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is *no* “typical convention” of storing arrays (and any other objects) in CSV columns. CSV is supposed to store text values.

If you want to have them in the single column, just join the array:

```
csv << hash.values.map { |e| [*e].join(',') }
```